# How to return only one column from MongoDB getUsers() output

Tags: mongodb-query

In the MongoDB shell, I want to find all the users who have dbOwner role for a particular db.  My query looks like this:

`db.getUsers( {filter:{"roles":{"role":"dbOwner", "db":"my_database"}}} )`

Which will return rows like:

```
[
        {
                "_id" : "admin.jsmith",
                "user" : "jsmith",
                "db" : "admin",
                "roles" : [
                        {
                                "role" : "dbOwner",
                                "db" : "my_database"
                        },
                        {
                                "role" : "dbOwner",
                                "db" : "other_db1"
                        },
                        {
                                "role" : "dbOwner",
                                "db" : "other_db2"
                        },
                        {
                                "role" : "MyCustomRole",
                                "db" : "admin"
                        }
                ],
                "mechanisms" : [
                        "REDACTED"
                ]
        }
]
```

My question is, how can I display just the "user" field?  I know this is probably simple once you know how, but I can't figure out how to do a projection for getUsers() output (different from doing a projection on the output of a collection query)

Thanks in advance

Ben